# Android: how to create app Help Dialog for first run

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm looking possibility to create transparent Help Dialog for app first run (when Android runs at first):
Help Dialog in Android: 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF1fK.png)

Are some standard Android APIs for that purpose?

If no, can I use custom Alert Dialog?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Use shared preference to store the values to identify it is first run or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[showcase view](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/showcase-view/)** library. It will serve your purpose. This is hosted in [github](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not use this dialog but read below link carefully, it will help and its have a standered.
https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/help.html

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you use `ShowcaseView` library! This is one of the most famous tutorial libraries in Android. Here is the simplest example for it with clear guide [Link](https://github.com/blundell/ShowcaseViewExample) and here is the [Link](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) of the main Library with full customization option.

[image]